# Induction heater

Tags: heat, induction

Please help me out. I am totally confused. I am searching over the internet many times but failed.

My question is:

Doe inductor coil (chock) decide resonance frequency of induction heating coil, when connects to the center tap of heating coil? If yes then how to decide the value for choke and heating coil. Which of them should be greater than the other.

I tell you that what I understand... If I am incorrect then please correct me. I understand from internet and youtube that resonant frequency in induction heater is the frequency at which heating coil switches the current.it may be from several Hz to kHz and MHz. And if we can calculate resonance frequency from heating coil and capacitor, then what the choke coil is doing there connected at center tap of heating coil.

[image: photo of induction heater]

Comment: Is your shift key malfunctioning?

Comment: We use English here.  Even beginners can follow simple and universal rules, like capitalizing the word "I", and capitalizing the first letter of every sentence.  Also, your first paragraph is completely content free.

Comment: @Winny: Clear he's just too lazy to use it, and doesn't respect us enough to care.  Help us out by -1 and voting to close.

Comment: Come out of rulebook to earn something incredible. Respect should be inside , using just a shift key does not teach you how to respect. I am not here to win a medal, and if it really matters to be on the rule here then i will take care of it .

Comment: @raj Using the language correctly helps make sure you get the meaning across correctly - mistakes with electricity can be fatal.

Comment: A center tap implies a push-pull design. Your asking at least 5 questions that are not very clear. VTC for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a ZVS oscillator circuit that uses a non centre-tapped heater coil but two chokes like this one: -

[image]

[Picture source](https://spaco.org/Blacksmithing/ZVSInductionHeater/1000WattZVSInductionHeaterNotes.htm).

In the design above the single induction coil is made resonant by the parallel capacitor bank and the two chokes are there just to provide a DC path for the drains of the MOSFETs. The inductance of these chokes is usually ten times that of the induction heater coil and will slightly increase the resonant frequency because their net effect is to lower the induction coil inductance.

Now, if you don't want two chokes you can split the induction coil and centre feed it with one choke from the power rail like this: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://gaugeboson.com/electronics/high_voltage.html).

This 2nd circuit has a different application i.e. it uses a regular HF transformer to generate sparks but the circuit functions the same.

The two choke version is a modification of the original single choke version and is, in fact, the same basic circuit copied and probably modified in something like paint.

But, the point is that either version gives the same performance and the choke(s) will slightly lower the bare inductance of the heater coil and increase the resonant frequency a tad.

Comment: Thankyou sir,
so basically chokes are provided just a path for DC to the MOSFETs drains and their values is 10 times then heating coil. And it does not decide the resonant frequency. And resonant frequency is depend on only Heating coil inductance value and a parallel capacitor with it.

Comment: There is a small change in frequency with the choke and not all circuits like this will rely on 10 to 1 inductance ratio; some may only be 4 or 5 to 1.

Comment: I got it sir, thankyou.
I just want to ask a random question,i am just curious about it. My question is, suppose we have two coil having same number of turns and same guage, now suppose primary coil is operating from 12 volt Ac, and having frequency Between 5khz - 10khz. And it induceses some voltage in the secondry coil wirelesslely when placed upon primary coil, so what would be the effect on secondary coil voltage when frequency of primary coil increases.

Comment: The secondary voltage will remain at the same value because primary current has reduced due to primary inductive reactance increasing but rate of change of flux has increased and the two effects cancel out.

Comment: And if number of turns and wire guage of secondry coil increased , will this affect the voltage and current of secondry coil to some value.

Comment: More secondary turns means more secondary voltage but load current naturally falls for a given power fed into the primary. You maybe should consider raising a question about transformers and how they work.

Comment: Sir i know that overall power in transformer is same. But on youtube someone creating more power by placing a bifiler coil over induction heater coil, thats why i asked you that how one make more output power than input, thats why i thought may be frequency of heating coil matters in producing more voltage and current. Is that guy on youtube doing something fake.

Comment: Power_out = power_in minus losses. There are no free lunches with power or energy.